# How to add a progressive IDs to elements with jquery?

Tags: jquery, addattribute

Using jquery I want to add an id to a series of divs, but of course the ids need to be always different, so I thought to have a progressive number like id="1", id="2", id="3" etc.

here's my markup:

content

```
    <div class="box">
        <p>
            content
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
        <p>
            content
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
        <p>
            content
        </p>
    </div>
```

I tried an .each() loop but I don't know what to pass as collection (maybe $('.box').lenght()? but returns a number not a collection) and how to implement the callback function.
any help please?

Thanks in advance :)

Mauro

Comment: Worth noting, just to be clear, that HTML IDs can't start with a number

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) like this:

```
$(".box").each(function(i, div) {
  div.id = "div" + (i+1); //i starts at 0
});
```

IDs can't start with a number, not in HTML4 anyway, so I've added a prefix above.  The [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) callback function receives the the index and the element as arguments, it's 0-based so add `1` if you want it to start with `1`.

[You can test it out here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/K5HQT/).

Answer (score 3):

[`.attr()` accepts functions](http://api.jquery.com/attr)

```
$(".box").attr('id', function(i) {
    return 'div_' + i;
});
```